# Need change an array to add a comma at the end of each 'text', but a dot in the end of last 'text' in object

Tags: javascript

```
const arr = [
  { id: 1, text: "123" },
  { id: 2, text: "456" },
  { id: 3, text: "789" },
];
```

For example now its looks like that ^^^, but need to make it smth like that:

```
const arr = [
  { id: 1, text: "123," },
  { id: 2, text: "456," },
  { id: 3, text: "789." },
];
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you know about forEach() or map()? Why is this tagged with CSS, HTML and React when it has nothing to do with any of those?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "123"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "456"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "789"
  },
]

const newArr = arr.map(({
  id,
  text
}, idx) => ({
  id,
  text: `${text}${idx < arr.length -1 ? "," : "."}`
}))

console.log(newArr)
```